# controller's function won't work in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

### The button code is

```
<div class="btn-group" align="center">
    <button ng-click="myFunction()" id="one" class='btn btn-primary btn1' >Save Entry</button>
    <button ng-click="close_window()" id="two" class='btn btn-primary btn2'>Exit</button>
</div>
```

### The New controller is

```
var app=angular.module('userApp',[])
    app.ng-controller('userController', function($scope)){
        $scope.myFunction = function(){
            var change= document.getElementById("one")
            if (change.innerHTML == "Save Entry")
            {
                change.innerHTML = "Saved!";
            }
            else 
            {
                change.innerHTML = "Save Entry";
            }
            return
        }

        $scope.close_window = function() {
            if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
                window.close();
            }      
        }
    }
```

this below code was working fine if i didn't add any controller and just declared function's like

```
function myFunction(){
    var change= document.getElementById("one")
    if (change.innerHTML == "Save Entry")
    {
        change.innerHTML = "Saved!";
    }
    else 
    {
        change.innerHTML = "Save Entry";
    }
}

function close_window() {
    if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
    close();
}
```

but when i add the controller the buttons would stop working. I tried every function definitions and answers on stack overflow but nothing seem to be working correctly. How do i get to button's work inside controller like they used to be working?

Comment: Change this `app.ng-controller` to `app.controller`, which is the correct syntax for making a controller.

Comment: a semicolon is missing `var app=angular.module('userApp',[])`. also you need to change the controller code like below `app.controller`

Comment: corrected those still not working.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app=angular.module('userApp',[])
    app.controller('userController', function($scope){
        $scope.myFunction = function(){
            var change= document.getElementById("one")
            if (change.innerHTML == "Save Entry")
            {
                change.innerHTML = "Saved!";
            }
            else 
            {
                change.innerHTML = "Save Entry";
            }
            return
        }

        $scope.close_window = function() {
            if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
                window.close();
            }      
        }
    });
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="userApp" ng-controller="userController">
<div class="btn-group" align="center">
    <button ng-click="myFunction()" id="one" class='btn btn-primary btn1' >Save Entry</button>
    <button ng-click="close_window()" id="two" class='btn btn-primary btn2'>Exit</button>
</div>
</body>
```

you are using `app.ng-controller` it should be `app.controller`.`ng-controller` is a directive, used to define controller in view.

```
app.controller('userController', function($scope){
    .......
})
```

Comment: have you specified `controller` for the view in routing or html file? Like `ng-controller = "userController"`

Comment: Yes i did like this
    <body ng-app="userApp" ng-controller="userController">

Comment: No the page is working fine but the functions are not doing their specified work.

Comment: i have updated my answer with working snippet, please check, hope it would help!!

Comment: thanks @the_mishra now it's working fine...!! Thanks a ton!!